# possible resulting values of shared variable x

Tags: race-condition

If we have two different processes with shared variable x, what are the possible values of x when both processes have completed?

Process A is running the following for-loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    x++
```

Process B is running:

```
for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    x--
```

I want to say x can be anywhere from -5 to 5, assuming x is initialized to 0.  Is this true?  Please include an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the compiler will generate a single instruction that will increment `x++` or decrement `x--`, it will have the same value it had before the for loops were executed after both threads are done, which is 0.

Otherwise, let's take the following example:

```
x++:
1. MOV R1, x     //register R1 receives x
2. INC R1        //register R1 is incremented
3. MOV x, R1     //store decremented x back to the memory
```

and

```
x--:
1. MOV R1, x     //register R1 receives x
2. DEC R1        //register R1 is decremented
3. MOV x, R1     //store decremented x back to the memory
```

It is quite obvious now that if one thread looses the CPU after executing line 1, it will have a value which is not updated, which will lead to a race condition and the variable will then have any value beetwen -5 and +5 after both threads are done with their execution, as you pointed out, depending on the different order of execution that both threads can have.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Imagine this scenario:

Both process A and process B (let's call them thread for clarity), get to the first iteration of the loop. Both threads retrieve the value of `x` (0), keep a local copy of that, compute their increment/decrement, and then race each other to update the register/memory containing `x`. Let's say A stores first, and B stores second. The resulting value of `x` is now -1.

Repeat this four more times and `x` ends up as `-5`.

Reverse the race above, and `x` ends up as `5`.